# Most efficient way to retrieve key from value in a Hashmap without using BiMap

Tags: java

I'm counting words in a file and i've loaded the words and their respective counts into a hash map. I've sorted the values and use this to retrieve my key:

```
public static String getKey(TObjectIntHashMap<String> hash, int value){
    for(String s: hash.keySet()){
        if(value == hash.get(s)){
            key = s;
            hash.remove(key);
            return key;
    }
}
```

I know this is a pretty ugly way to do it, but it's the only way I can seem to get to work. I'm completely aware of the existence of bimaps, but would prefer not to use one. Any ideas?

Comment: You should make clear that you are asking about `TObjectIntHashMap`, not `java.util.HashMap`, in the title.

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use the most time-efficient solution?  Space constraints?

Comment: Depending on how often you do this it might be better to construct a reverse Map<Integer, List<String>>.  This can be done in O(N) time.

Comment: Is it faster? If so, then I was unaware. Perhaps I'll try to implement it again. I was running into a bunch of run time errors and i'm on sort of a time-crunch so I didn't bother to delve deeper. I'll try to do it right now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more efficient way to do this would be to use an iterator, since this avoids having to do a separate lookup of the key and value:

```
public static String getKey(TObjectIntHashMap<String> hash, int value){
    TObjectIntIterator<String> iterator = hash.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      iterator.advance();
      if (iterator.value() == value) {
        key = iterator.key();
        iterator.remove();
        return key;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that if I can't get the bimap going.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is using a `Multiset` from guava collections. This is simple code:

```
//create multiset
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();

//add some strings
multiset.add("a");
multiset.add("a");
multiset.add("b");

//sort and print
System.out.println(Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(multiset).entrySet();
```

More about `Multiset`, you can find here:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset

Comment: Thanks! I'll read more into that one. Looks like it would be pretty useful.

Comment: The `Multimap` is some like `Map<T, Integer>', it's mean you can check how many times you added the same element to the collection.